# how to add two button in navigation bar with some space

Tags: ipad, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I am adding two button in navigation bar they are working fine but i want space between them they are both combined i want a bit space between them

```
  UIBarButtonItem *btnAdd = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(Add)];

UIBarButtonItem *btnEdit = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Add"
                                                           style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain
                                                          target:self
                                                          action:@selector(Add)];


UIToolbar *rightToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 44)];
rightToolBar.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
rightToolBar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:40.0/255.0 green:48.0/255.0 blue:51.0/255.0 alpha:0.0];
NSArray *buttonsRight = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:btnEdit, btnAdd, nil];
[rightToolBar setItems:buttonsRight];

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:rightToolBar];
```

Answer (score 1):

You can add any of these two between your `UIBarButtonItem`

```
UIBarButtonItem *fixed = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFixedSpace target:nil action:nil]

UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil]
```

Note that to set the width of a Fixed Space `UIBarButtonItem`, you need to set the `.width` property

```
[fixed setWidth:455.0f];
```

Comment: i have done like this but not spacing i want one on right side and one with a 30 pixels space on that